# 関数を定義する方法が分からない

Tags: python

画面に「hello」と表示するprint_hello()関数を定義したいのですがどのようにするべきなのでしょうか？

```
# TODO ここに「hello」と表示するprint_hello関数を定義してください

print_hello()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

関数の定義は`def`文で行います。
また、今回は必要ありませんが、戻り値がある関数は`return 値`と関数の最後に記述します。
よって、中で`print("hello")`を実行する関数の定義は

```py
def print_hello() :
    print("hello")
```

になります。

確認のため、定義した関数を呼び出して終了する場合は

```py
def print_hello() :
    print("hello")

print_hello()
```

となります。